# Error propagation in Gaussian processes

Tags: machine-learning, gaussian-process, error-propagation

I am trying to predict a time-series measurements, $x_{t+1},x_{t+2},...$ using a Gaussian process model, where the kernel is a Gaussian kernel with small noise-level $\sigma_w^2$, i.e. $k_{ij}=e^{-\frac{\Vert x_i-x_j\Vert_2^2}{\epsilon}}+\sigma_w^2$

Each feature vector $x_t$ consists of an interval in time of $k$ historical measurements, i.e. $x_t=[r_t, r_{t-1},...r_{t-k+1}]$. Suppose I want to predict the value of $r_{t+1}$, then given the Gaussian process formula, I get that:

$\hat{r}_{t+1}=k_*^TK^{-1}f$, where $f=[r_t,r_{t-1},...]$ and the variance is given by

$\text{var}(r_{t+1})=1+\sigma_r^2-k_*^TK^{-1}k_*$

Where $k_*=e^{-\frac{\Vert x_i-x_{t+1}\Vert_2^2}{\epsilon}}, i=1,...,t$ 
Now, suppose that at time $t$, I want to predict $r_{t+L}$, so what I was doing is predicting recursively $r_{t+1}$, then using it to predict $r_{t+2}$ and so on. The question is, how to predict the variance for $\hat{r}_{t+L}$ ? Since now I don't use $r_{t-k}$ for some $k$, which are determined, but rather $\hat{r}_{t-k}$ which are estimated with some variance.

Trying to block the error in a straight forward way, using error propagation approaches does not seem to be very elegant.

I hope the question is clear, I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Since you seem to be interested in forecasting a time series $r_t$,
why not use standard techniques? The model underlying your approach is
both unclear and strange, showing long-memory. Gaussian models for
time series are readily available 'on the shelf'.

Comment: yeah, you are right. I can use different models, but - I've tried this approach and gives good results + I can use the variance estimation as a confidence interval... and I find it interesting from the theoretical perspective as well.